# About two Bernoulli experiment

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Say there are two Bernoulli random variables: $X_1$ and $X_2$ with different $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. Now let them each perform $N$ trials, my question is how to calculate the possibility such that $N(X_1) > N(X_2)$? $N()$ means the successful number of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in their $N$-time trials.

Comment: Not easily, but $N(X_1)$ and $N(X_2)$ are Binomially distributed random variables with trial-amount parameter $N$, and rate parameters $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ respectively.

Comment: Are the trials and random variables independent? If so, something like $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} P(N(X_1) > i)*P(N(X_2)=i)$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got, but it seems there is no closed-form formula for this...

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with the notation $N(X_1)$.